# Vertically centering a div on top of an absolutely positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have a website with a main body content section. In this body content section there is an element that is positioned towards the bottom absolutely, with a bit of space between it and the footer.

Now, I've tried quite a lot and exhausted my thinking capabilities to try and get the other part of my body content to be vertically centred between that absolutely positioned bottom element and the top of the screen (in this case the top of the body section since there is also a header).

If I do the vertical align method using table cells then the problem is that my `height : 100%` option doesn't work here since then the content is indeed centred between the header and the footer but I need it to be centred between the header and my absolutely positioned bottom content above the footer.

Further to your comments here is a demo link: http://smartlights.azurewebsites.net/

A further extension is that because this is a responsive website design eh bottom absolute row can actually end up having two possible heights. Is this possible in CSS or does javascript then definitely have to be involved?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or a demo link to get useful answers

Comment: To the element that you are trying to center, add `margin` or `padding` (I am not sure which one) equal to the height of the bottom element. and just center it in the screen.

Comment: @akonsu thanks - it seems to work - very simple solution, sometimes you just have a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform: translate` to vertically center elements.

First, set the element to `position: absolute`, or `position: relative`, and push it down 50% of its parent's height with `top: 50%`. Like this:

```
.vertical-align {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Now the top of the element `.vertical-align` will be aligned to the middle of its parent. All you need to do now is push it up 50% of *its own* height. This can be done with javascript if you feel like it, but I really like doing it with `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

```
.vertical-align {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here's a pen of this in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ckyvz

Here's the browser support for 3d transforms: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Remember to prefix the `transform`-property with the regular browser vendor prefixes.

Have fun!

Comment: This is all good - thanks for the answer - but it till doesn't solve the problem of vertically centring it between the top of the parent element and the absolutely positioned bottom div (of variable height) :(

Comment: Thanks though - once I figured out how to get my container div to end at the appropriate place this is a much better way fo doing it than using table cells

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc();`

```
.center_div{
    height:calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

assuming height of the absolute div is 200px

Comment: That would work perfectly and is probably a better solution to using padding. What however would I do if that absolute div could either be 160px or 320px high? If you have a look at the website link and you shrink the screen left then the picture icons split over two rows.

Comment: Media query to the rescue :)

Answer (score 0):

you can align an element to center with this method.

```
element{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

this for vertical align center.

```
element{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto 0;
}
```